# How can I remove words in a sentence starting with a particular set of characters?

Tags: python, regex

I want to use regular expression in Python to remove certain words in a sentence that start with a specific set of characters.

For example: If I have a string `"searches for IPhone 5s search results"`, I want to remove all the words that start with search. Thus, the result should be: `"for IPhone 5s results"`

I used this:

```
query=re.sub(r"/search\w+/", "", query)
```

but this doesn't remove the `es` from searches

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
query=re.sub(r"\bsearch\w+", "", query)

               ^^         ^^
```

You dont need `/` here in python.

Comment: I tried with special characters like @ but it doesn't work... is there a work around in such case?

Comment: @FedericoGentile for that u can simply use @\w+

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was also leaving the \b that's why it didn't work :)

Answer (score 1):

This would work for you

```
query=re.sub(r"\bsearch\w+", "", query)
```

**\b:** sets up a boundary for the word search

**\w+:** captures the remaining words after search have been matched.

Hope this helps